# Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, active-directory, ldap

Some Computer can't connect to our active directory server. I don't know if there's a problem in my code cause its working to other PC. I'm using .net framework 4.0. All PCs are connected to the same network. It can ping our AD server. PLEASE HELP!

```
public bool CheckADAccount(string strUserAccount, bool Stat)
    {
        try {
            DirectoryEntry rootDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dbADServer + "/CN=Users," + "DC=companyname,DC=net,DC=ph", dbADUser, dbADPass);
            DirectorySearcher DirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(rootDirEntry, "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + strUserAccount + "))");

            DirSearcher.PageSize = 5;
            DirSearcher.ServerTimeLimit = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            DirSearcher.ClientTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            DirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

            SearchResultCollection SearchResultCol = DirSearcher.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult Result in SearchResultCol)
            {
                adAccountName = Result.Properties["cn"][0].ToString();
                Stat = true;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "System Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);  
            Stat = false;
        }
        return Stat;
    }
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.